# Need Solidity software for smart contract, for Multiple Token dispatch

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-design, contract-invocation

Please I need to distribute tokens to at least 1,500 wallets and can't go through the stress of sending them one by one.

What I need is a smart contract to enable multiple dispatches to several wallets simultaneously.

I would appreciate it if I can get the code for the above issue.

FYI: I dont know too much about coding.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

I am maintaining a token distribution script [here](https://ico.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html#distribute-tokens).

[It is using Issuer smart contracts here](https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/ico/tree/master/contracts).

As a disclaimer I am not going to provide any support for people how do not have a basic understanding of Solidity, smart contract programming and such. I strongly feel that people should train themselves to a proper experience level before engaging into blockchain and token industries. So if you have a *need* and you do not know how to do it, you are already screwing up yourself or somebody else.